# Seemingly empty vector

Tags: c++, vector

I've added some slight multi threading to a simple c++ program and have encountered a few issues along the way.

The latest of these issues is that **historical::assignthreads** for some reason is receiving an empty vector from the function **historical::writeData**.

Looking at the code below you will see that writeData iterates through a vector and puts the data in a placeholder before sending it forward to assignthreads (after 5 iterations) - meaning that the vector being sent from writeData to assignthreads shouldn't be empty.

However in assignthreads you will see that there are two cout:s, one before and one after the loop. Both writes to cout without the loop even starting.

Does anyone have any idea of how this could be the case?

```
void historical::writeData(std::vector<std::vector<std::wstring>> in, const string& symbol) {
    std::cout << "Sending data to database connector" << std::endl;
    std::vector<std::vector<std::wstring>> temp;
    std::vector<std::vector<std::wstring>>::iterator it;
    int count = 0;
    for (it = in.begin(); it != in.end(); it++) {
        if (count = 5) {
            cout << "I'm in count 5" << endl;
            assignthreads(temp, symbol);
            temp.clear();
            count = 0;
        }
        else {
            cout << "I'm in count 0" << endl;
            temp.push_back(*it);
            count++;
        }

    }
    if (!temp.empty()) {
        cout << "I'm in empty" << endl;
        assignthreads(temp, symbol);
    }
    else cout << "I'm empty!!" << endl;
}
void historical::assignthreads(std::vector<std::vector<std::wstring>>& partVec, const string& symbol) {
    int i = 0;
    cout << "I'm in assign" << endl;
    vector<thread> threads(size(partVec));
    std::vector<std::vector<std::wstring>>::iterator it;
    for (it = partVec.begin();
         it != partVec.end();
         it++) {
        cout << "I'm in the loop" << endl;
        std::shared_ptr<database_con> sh_ptr(new database_con);
        threads.at(i) = std::thread(&database_con::start, sh_ptr, *it, symbol);
        i++;
    }
    cout << "I've finished" << endl;
    for (auto& th : threads) th.join();

}

void historical::writer(string* pInput) {
    ofstream mf("test.csv");
    if (mf.is_open()) {
        mf << *pInput;
        mf.close();
    }
    else cout << "Unable to open file" << endl;
}
```

Comment: `if (count = 5)` is always `true` (i.e. `5`)

Comment: if developing under linux, try clang++ as compiler for better/more compiler warnings. AFAIK clang warns you about assignments in if conditions.

Comment: @Markus I'd imagine `g++` would too if `-Wall` was set

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your fundamental problem here is that `count = 5` is an assignment and is therefore always true. You intended to use `count == 5`.

---

It's worth noting that particularly as your vector becomes large copying it is very wasteful, and you're doing this 2 ways:

1. The `vector` is passed into `writeData` by value, change to copying by reference: `void writeData(std::vector<std::vector<std::wstring>>& in, const string& symbol)`
2. `temp` will eventually copy every element of `in`, use iterators instead so your code would have to change to:

```
#define SIZE 5

void assignthreads(std::vector<std::vector<std::wstring>>::iterator start, std::vector<std::vector<std::wstring>>::iterator finish, const string& symbol) {
    cout << "I'm in assign" << endl;

    vector<thread> threads(distance(start, finish));

    for(auto i = 0; start != finish; ++i, ++start) {
        cout << "I'm in the loop" << endl;
        std::shared_ptr<database_con> sh_ptr(new database_con);
        threads.at(i) = std::thread(&database_con::start, sh_ptr, *start, symbol);
    }
    cout << "I've finished" << endl;

    for (auto& th : threads) th.join();
}

void writeData(std::vector<std::vector<std::wstring>>& in, const string& symbol) {
    std::cout << "Sending data to database connector" << std::endl;

    auto count = 0;

    while(count < in.size() - SIZE) {
        auto start = next(in.begin(), count);

        count += SIZE;

        auto finish = next(in.begin(), count);

        assignthreads(start, finish, symbol);
    }

    assignthreads(next(in.begin(), count), in.end(), symbol);

    cout << "I'm empty!!" << endl;
}
```

Comment: God, am I an idiot... That's what I meant with just being so damn tired atm and just wanting to get through it.

However, now I'm getting some debug error with no stack trace.. :/

Comment: @NathanOliver I wanted to give some further improvement advice along with the solution, but I got called away in the middle of the answer. I've corrected that with an edit.

Comment: that helped immensefully. However, there is some compilation errors when adding as is to the solution - look at the size(partVec).

Comment: @geostocker Sorry [`size`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/size) is C++17, as long as the object you're working with is a `vector` or other standard container you can use `partVec.size()` anywhere I used `size(partVec)`.

Comment: Yeah I got that part. :)
It's just that there is no object (no partVec) in the parameters anymore - only start, finish and symbol! :)

Comment: @geostocker Ugh my apologies. Clearly I did not build this code. That should have said `SIZE` not `size(partVec)`. I've corrected it in the answer, but it may be worth noting that if `assignthreads` is misused there could be a segfault. Consider adding `assert(threads.size() == distance(start, finish))` after `threads` is defined.

Comment: still seem to be some issues. Still getting debug errors as well as assertion failed too. :/

Comment: @geostocker So I've dumped some code here: http://ideone.com/DHIo5X I can't build this cause I don't have the `database_con` object. Could you maybe paste in a stubbed out header for that object and I could take a further look?

Comment: @Jonatahan Mee Added a fork to the source with the database_con.cpp and the header.

Comment: So, it won't compile at all, getting errors regarding linking, a mismatch in the while (count < in.size() - SIZE) amongs two other issues.

The problem I faced with the previous ideone that you posted was that i t compiles and runs, but almost instantly I'm faced with a debug error which I am assuming is from one of the parent threads, as the program keeps running the other threads.
To clarify: it seems one historical-thread keeps running whilst the other 4 gives me a debug error and ends within a few seconds..

Comment: see this picture for an example. (Program still running) http://imgur.com/VNihi0i

Comment: @geostocker Feel free to post an error here, it doesn't have any issues compiling in http://ideone.com so I feel like there may have been a copy paste error. The error should tell you what the problem is. I would have expected the `th.join()` would have terminated all the threads.

Comment: @geostocker Ah, excellent. It looks like there is a problem in your thread's code. Fortunately you can hit retry and debug into what's going on.

Comment: @geostocker Haha, note the one modified line in the image you just sent. `count += 15` that must always be `count += SIZE` do you understand why?

Comment: Yeah, I know exactly why it has to be size. However, I did change the definition of size to 15, so that shouldn't be an issue, if I'm not completely off base?
Regardless, even changing it to size and setting size to 5 (as was default) the error(s) occur.

Comment: @geostocker You're saying it still errors on the `assert`. That would mean that the `start` and `finish` are not exactly `SIZE` apart. Which shouldn't be possible if you are doing `count += SIZE`. Can you validate that the `assert` is tripping and not something else?

Comment: I'm not really sure how to validate that it's the assert that is messing with me, but having run it a few times more I've found three possible suspects:
* The last assignthreads call, an empty space in historical::go (empty row after writeData is initially called) and assert.
There were also issues in the database_con where I extract the data and create the wstring to be sent to SQL, but that must be a false positive. :/

Comment: @geostocker Ah, one thing I missed is, I told you to do `assert(threads.size() == distance(start, finish))` but unless `in.size() % SIZE == 0` there will be a final run of `assignthreads` where `start` and `finish` are less than `SIZE` apart. So rather than doing the `assert` let me recommend that we do: `vector<thread> threads(distance(start, finish));` that way we're not wasteful and we *know* we won't iterate past the end. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: Well, even with that the debug errors are happening.
I'm honestly not really sure what the hell could be happening. 

The only other part that I added was in the root of the program. If you have time, would you be able to have a quick look at this: http://ideone.com/3JBnkc

Comment: @geostocker Where are the debug errors happening? When you click "Retry" what line does it take you to? We need to figure out what inputs are bad to that line.

Comment: Using the debugger it seems like the errors occur in the call to executeQuery and the last part of buildQuery. http://ideone.com/HPWZeX

Comment: The problem I have with that is that every vector<wstring> that comes in the vector<vector<wstring>> is the same, with the same amount of columnts. So there shouldn't be any issues. And if there was an issue, the show_error would say something - in this case it doesn't. It simply shows the debugger without any stack trace in the console (unless it's just too quick for me to react).

Comment: @geostocker I had some bugs in the code that I originally posted, but it looks like we have debugged that portion, and now we're onto finding bugs in other parts of your program. So lets open a new question again and discuss `executeQuery` there. Again, please post the link here so I can find the question when you link it.